# bartering items by exchanging this with this?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> He's now bartering items by exchanging this with this

I was told that you should use "for" instead of "with", but then someone told me it's ok to use "with" if you want to say you're directly exchanging one for another, is this the case? When can you use "with" instead of "for"?

Comment: Have a look at [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exchanged+it+with+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing the most common words to follow ***exchanged it with...*** As you'll see, mostly it's the ***names of people*** with whom an exchange was conducted. Most competent native speakers wouldn't use ***with*** for the thing exchanged, but [it's a very different story with ***replaced with / by***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/), if you're interested.

Comment: And I doubt many native speakers would ever use ***this*** twice in one utterance to refer to different things. It's always ***this*** and ***that***.

Comment: If you have to things on a shelf and swap their position you might "exchange the books with the magazines". But "for" expresses the value of something used in a trade or exchange: "he bought the book for five dollars". So in bartering you probably want to use "for". Note that "for" can also mean the beneficiary (e.g. buying a present for someone), and "with" can mean the person you do the trade with", so you may vary your preposition to avoid replication, although "He swapped the picture for a necklace for his wife" sounds OK.

Answer (score 0):

"Exchange with" is common in some contexts: if you have to things on a shelf and swap their position you might "exchange the books with the magazines". But "for" expresses the *value* of something used in a trade or exchange ([Merriam-Webster "for" preposition sense 8a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)): "he bought the book for five dollars". So in bartering you probably want to use "for": "he exchanged the book for the meat" indicates there was a trade where the book and the meat had the same value and were exchanged for each other.

But this isn't a hard and fast rule, and you will see "with" used occasionally. Note that "for" can also mean the beneficiary (e.g. buying a present for someone), and "with" can mean the person you do the trade with, so you might vary your preposition to avoid ambiguity or replication, although "He swapped the picture for a necklace for his wife" sounds OK to me despite the repetition.

If you're talking about two people/groups doing a trade between themselves, you can still use "for", e.g. "The tribes exchanged grain for meat". It's also possible to use "and" in this context: "They exchanged grain and meat".

Answer (score 0):

We would never say

> I'll trade you my  bicycle *with* your computer.

It would be **for** when talking about a swap or trade and referring to the items in the exchange.

**with** is used in situations involving a replacement or a change of place:

> He replaced the original solder **with** a wad of chewing gum to effect a crude repair of the loose wire.

and that's so even when the verb "swap" is used:

> He swapped the big dictionary with the world atlas to improve the bookshelf's *feng shui*.

It is "tit for tat" not "tit with tat".

Answer (score 0):

> He's now bartering items by exchanging this with [that].

We should use **for** in *exchange "things" ... "things"* constructions.  [Collins Dictionary says in its 2.VERB B2 section](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/exchange):

> If the car you have leased is clearly unsatisfactory, you can always exchange it **for** another. [VERB noun + **for**][emphasis added]

The same dictionary explains the use of *with* in its 1.VERB B1+ section:

> He exchanged a quick smile **with her** then entered the lift. [VERB noun + with]

[Ngram shows that "exchange *NOUN* **for** *NOUN*" is more common that the **with** version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exchange+_NOUN_+for+_NOUN_%2Cexchange+_NOUN_+with+_NOUN_&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).  Furthermore, as the *with* cases would have included the **exchange noun + with "person"** constructions, the actual number of **with** cases in *exchange* "things" ... "things" constructions should be much lower.  I doubt many of the remaining cases are from competent speakers.